# Por que a matriz não imprime todos os valores digitados?

Tags: c, matriz, memória

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

int linha=0, coluna=0, i, j, l, m;
int matriz_A[linha][coluna], matriz_B[linha][coluna], matriz_C[linha] 
[coluna];
char escolha = '0';

printf("\n Qual operação com matrizes você quer fazer? ");
printf("\n (1) Adição");
printf("\n (2) Subtração");
printf("\n (3) Multiplicação \n");
scanf("%c%*[^\n]", &escolha);

if(escolha =='1')
{
    printf("\n Informe quantas linhas terá a matriz: ");
    scanf("%i", &linha);

    printf("\n Informe quantas colunas terá a matriz: ");
    scanf("%i", &coluna);

    printf("\n Informe os valores da matriz A: \n");
      for(i=0; i<linha; i++)
      {
          for(j=0; j<coluna; j++)
          {
              scanf("%d", &matriz_A[i][j]);
          }
      }

    printf("\n Informe os valores da matriz B: \n");
      for(l=0; l<linha; l++)
      {
          for(m=0; m<coluna; m++)
          {
              scanf("%d", &matriz_B[l][m]);
          }
      }

     printf("\n Abaixo temos a matriz A \n");
       for(i=0; i<linha; i++)
       {
           for(j=0; j<coluna; j++)
           {
             printf(" %d ", matriz_B[i][j]);
           }
          printf("\n");
       }


}

return 0;
}
```

Abaixo a saída quando eu ponho na matriz A 2x2, os valores 1234:

```
3 4
3 4
```

Por que o programa sempre imprime e repete somente os 2 últimos números que digito independente da ordem da matriz?

Eu percebi que isso é corrigido alterando o valor de inicialização das variáveis **linha** e **coluna** para qualquer valor maior que 0. Mas se eu estou atribuindo um valor para ambas no `scanf()` não era pra isso ser corrigido? Sempre que tento inicializar ambas sem nenhum valor elas pegam lixo da memoria.

Comment: Note que quando você declara suas matrizes as variáveis linha e coluna estão zeradas. Declare-as após a leitura destas variáveis (o que não funcionará em versões antigas dos compiladores) ou faça alocação dinâmica de memória.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não vi tudo e parece que o código nem está completo, mas o maior problema que tem aí é que não está reservando espaço para a matriz. Veja a linha:

```
int matriz_A[linha][coluna], matriz_B[linha][coluna], matriz_C[linha][coluna];
```

Quanto vale `linha` e `coluna` no momento dessa declaração? 0, certo? Então vamos reescrever com o valor em vez das variáveis.

```
int matriz_A[0][0], matriz_B[0][0], matriz_C[0][0];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/RowXCol.c).

Está reservando espaço para 3 matrizes com tamanho zero.

Provavelmente quer criar essas matrizes depois de perguntar os valores de `linha` e `coluna`.

Até funciona mais ou menos, mas por pura coincidência, e temos que entender o que estamos fazendo e determinar o certo. Por alguma razão as pessoas acreditam que se mandar executar e der o resultado esperado o código está certo, quando na verdade ele só funcionou, por coincidência. Quando não funciona, aí a pessoa resolve ver o que tá acontecendo. Então deu sorte desta vez porque não funcionou. O aprendizado aqui é que não pode confiar no que acontece e sim dominar o que o código faz em cada ponto, em cada mínimo detalhe, até mesmo os espaços em branco que usou, se não fizer isto não está programando.

O erro deve ter ocorrido por uma mania que as pessoas tem de declarar todas variáveis no começo da aplicação e não só quando precisa, se elas se atentassem para o correto este tipo de erro não ocorreria, este erro eu até entendo, alguém ensinou que deveria ser assim há 30 anos, e na época só podia ser assim, mas tudo mudou e as pessoas continuaram ensinando assim, mesmo que não era um bom jeito, a nova forma foi criada porque ela é melhor e deveria ser ensinada por todos, mas não é o que acontece, por isso questiono a qualidade do que tem se ensinado por aí.

Comment: a outra parte do codigo e so impressão da matriz B (com mesmo problema) e a impressão da soma das 2 matrizes